# Swift NSKeyedUnarchiver Failing After Converting from String to Data

Tags: swift, nscoding

I have a class that conforms to NSCoding. I want to convert that class into data, then into a string that can be stored on backend.

The issue is that once it's a converted from a `String` back to `Data` it fails to unarchive properly with `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, so converting to a string must be corrupting the data.

Here's the code:

```
  do {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: drawItems, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        let stringData = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        
        print("HERE successfully converted to a string: ", stringData)
        
        let stringBackToData: Data? = stringData.data(using: .utf8)
        if let stringBackToData = stringBackToData, let allItems = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(stringBackToData) as? [DrawItem] {
            print("HERE items: ", allItems)
        } else {
            print("HERE FAILED to unarchive")
        }
        
    catch {
            print("Failed: ", error)
    }
```

What is wrong with this string conversion?

Comment: Are you hitting the `catch` block and getting an error? If so, what does it say? So you're aware, the default output format from `NSKeyedArchiver` is a _binary_ format that doesn't form valid UTF-8, so attempting to decode it as UTF-8 is lossy, and your data is likely getting corrupted in the process. The error may give you more information about what's going on here. (Is there a reason you can't store the `Data` directly in the backend?)

Comment: @ItaiFerber nope, not hitting the catch -- hitting the else case in the NSKeyedUnarchiver. How would you convert the data to a string to upload to a backend?

Comment: You have two main options: (1) don't use this convenience method on `NSKeyedArchiver`, but create an archiver directly and set its [`outputFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver/1417520-outputformat) to `.xml`, which should be writable as UTF-8, or (2) continue using this method, but convert it to a string using [`base64EncodedString(options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2142853-base64encodedstring). I don't know off the top of my head which will be more compact, but will check

Comment: @ItaiFerber if you can come up with a working solution with either of those I'll mark your answer as correct

Comment: Yep, you caught me as I was typing my comment up as an answer. :) Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [`outputFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver/1417520-outputformat) for `NSKeyedArchiver` is `.binary`, which is not convertible to or from UTF-8. In your example, `String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)` ["repairs"](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d1bb98b11ede375a1cee739f964b7d23b6657aaf/stdlib/public/core/String.swift#L449) invalid UTF-8 bytes by [replacing them](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d1bb98b11ede375a1cee739f964b7d23b6657aaf/stdlib/public/core/StringUTF8Validation.swift#L190) with the UTF-8 [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_sequences_and_error_handling) (`0xFFFD`).

This corrupts the archiver data, and prevents it from decoding properly.

If you really can't transmit binary data to your backend as-is, or store it that way, and must convert the data into a string, you have two options:

1. `NSKeyedArchiver` has an alternate `.outputFormat` of `.xml`, which produces UTF-8 XML data. You can produce this data by creating an archiver and configuring it:

   ```
   let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: false)
   archiver.outputFormat = .xml
   archiver.encode(drawItems, forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey)

   if let error = archiver.error {
       // Handle the error. This is the same error that would be produced
       // by `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:)`
   } else {
       let data = archiver.encodedData
       // `data` is UTF-8 XML data ready to be transmitted/stored
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can continue using the convenience method you are now, but [Base64 encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) it:

   ```
    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: drawItems, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    let base64EncodedData = data.base64EncodedString()
   ```

Which you use is up to you: on its own, the base64-encoded string is shorter than the raw XML data (because the starting binary data is significantly smaller than its equivalent XML), but the XML data does compress significantly better than the base64 data does, and may very well end up smaller. You can test both approaches to see what fits your use-case better.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!